# Match a path to a roadmap

Tags: spatial, matching

I do not know if I'm in the right place but let us go.
I got a relative path of an object. Which mean I know the distance and the direction between all the points of the path but do not know their GPS coordinates. I got a road map. I want to match the relative path to the road map as you can see in the picture. I did some search on Google but nothing close to my problem. Can you guide me?[image]

Comment: My initial thought is, since there's no real 'gradient' here, you probably need to brute force all possible rotations/positions. Perhaps you could quantise/downsample the map and path and brute force over that to find a shortlist of potential matches, then check each of these at higher resolution?

Comment: Since the map could be very large I'm kinda perplexed but thanks for your thougths, interesting

Comment: ¿Does the map contain distance data between nodes? And ¿what about angles between edges? If so, there could be a searching protocol that could be used to reduce the number of areas in the map that need to be searched.

Comment: Just some other initial thought: teach a neural net to do it.